# Angular JS filtering out used ids from a separate array

Tags: arrays, angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

I've got an object of articles which contain all the articles on a site by id in an ng-repeat. I also have an array inside a products object of attached articles by id in a repeat.

Trying to only show the articles that are NOT attached already to the product. Not really sure how to iterate over the arrays and find matches and exclude them from the returned object.

https://gist.github.com/irthos/0565c66be0ab992adc0a

Is there a way I can ng-repeat="article in articles | (except for when any product.articles.$id === article.$id)"?

Comment: Create a function on the scope that does what you want and pass it as an argument to `filter`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
var app = angular.module('app', []);
app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope) {
  $scope.name = 'World';
  $scope.search = 1;

  $scope.familes = [{
    id:1,
    name: "Kruders",
    kids: [
      { name: "zoe" } 
      ]
},

{
  id:2,
    name: "Halifax",
    kids: [
      { name: "mike" } ,
      { name: "jim" } 
      ]
},

{
  id:3,
    name: "Judes",
    kids: [
     
      ]
}]
});
```

```html
<html ng-app="app">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>

<body ng-controller="MainCtrl">
  <input type="number" ng-model="search" />



  <ul>
    <li ng-repeat="family in familes | filter  :{id:'!'+search}">id: {{family.id}} - Name:{{family.name}}</li>
  </ul>

</body>
  </html>
```

Please see that demo it should helps http://plnkr.co/edit/MNqBhOd1Y5GVezfa8zj0?p=preview

```
ng-repeat="article in articles | filter :{id:'!'+product.articles.$id})
```

Comment: Much appreciated sss! Very elegant. Only one thing I still don't see how to accomplish: how to have $scope.search = [1,2] so that the output would only be 3.

Comment: @irth in that case you need to create your custom filter please see  here http://plnkr.co/edit/oFeKpFFEH9HoxxcySGi0?p=preview